# How do you map values in LabVIEW? Is there a best way or convention?

Tags: labview

I have an angle in degrees, and need to map it to a voltage.

i.e. left: -360 degrees = 0V, straight: 0 degrees = 5V, right: 360 degrees = 10V.

How do you map values in LabVIEW?

I found scaling under the numeric pallet but they seem to be very specific (e.g. for a thermistor) with no generic block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the mapping you want is described by a mathematical formula, just implement that calculation using LabVIEW functions. In your case, assuming it's a linear relationship, the formula is **voltage = (angle + 360) / 72** .

You could code this in LabVIEW with an Add function followed by a Divide function, or if you think it's clearer written out as a formula then you could use a [Formula Node](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7572/en/).

If you need to use this calculation in more than one place in your application, make it into a subVI.

Comment: Just out of curiosity! why are you dividing by 72?

Comment: The asker wants to map an input range of 720 degrees (-360 to +360) on to an output range of 10 V. 720 / 10 = 72.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to read a analog gauge value! Actually it's very simple.

1. Build a lookup Table
2. Perform Interpolation followed by thresholding.

Refer the VI Snippet (Just paste this image into your block diagram).

[image: Block Diagram]

Sample Output:

[image: Front Panel]

Comment: This is a good explanation of how to implement a calibration curve as a series of linear segments, but it's not necessary for the OP's question which just needs a simple linear function.